# The places at which a journey begins and ends

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

In the nomenclature of travel and transport, what are the most common terms to describe the places at which a journey begins and ends?

I think that "**destination**" is likely to be the latter—but how do we describe the former?  My mathematical mind wants to say "**origin**" or "**source**", but I suspect those from a less scientific background may find those terms awkward; is there any better terminology?

Comment: *The Shire* and *Mordor* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you actually have the best answer—**origin**—in your question. It's relatively common and not "too technical/scientific." However, it is formal.

If you are looking for a colloquial alternative, the most common synonym of *origin* that I've heard is **starting point**.

> The *starting point* of our journey is Los Angeles, and we will travel to our destination, New York.

Interestingly, you'll see this in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/). The origin box is actually labeled "Choose starting point..."

Answer (score 1):

Itineraries and tickets usually describe this as point of departure and point of arrival.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the expression *jumping-off point* for the start of the journey.

> **[Jumping-off point](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/jumping-off-point)**: a point from which to start a journey or activity

And *destination/stop* for the last part of the journey.

Also see [Parts of Journey](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/parts-of-a-journey).

Comment: Those both sound, to my British ear, like very American terms—I've certainly never heard them used in this context before.  Perhaps I should have been more clear that this is for a British audience?

Comment: I can't recall ever hearing "home straight".  "Jumping-off point' is quite idiomatic (in the US), however.

Answer (score -1):

"We ***embarked*** on our journey from..."

Comment: I guess that would make the opposite of destination the...embarkation point?